# Python - object - df.type() - what is it ? What can I do with it?

Tags: python, object

I have spent my whole day, scratching my head and searching for infos without any success.

I am trying to import an XLS file. 28 columns. 1010 rows. 
In these rows/columns, I thought I would import basic int/float/strings ... 
And I thought that I would be able to make calculations between ints, and find some strings contained in some column values...

But that was a newbie utopia. as usual... ;)

here's the codes :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filename = ("D:/PRIVATE/Turb002/Downloads/suivialso3.xlsx")
df = pd.read_excel(filename)
df.columns = ['Reference','Artiste','Titre','Code_Prix','Sortie','Suppr','Profit_Center','O_D','J_2_QTE NETTE','J_1_QTE_NETTE','S_2_QTE_NETTE','S_1_QTE_NETTE','S_QTE_NETTE','M_1_QTE_NETTE','M_QTE_BRUTE','M_QTE_DEPOT_VENTE','M_QTE_RETOUR','M_QTE_STOCK_RACHETE','M_QTE_NETTE','ORIGINE_QTE_BRUTE','ORIGINE_QTE_RETOUR','ORIGINE_QTE_NETTE','CDES_EN _ATTENTE','PORTEFEUILLE_RETOUR','STOCK','STOCK_RETOUR','NON_ENCORE_RECONDITIONNABLE','STOCK_AVANCE']
df.dtypes
```

the answer to that :

```
>>> print (df.dtypes)
Référence                              object
Artiste                                object
Titre                                  object
Code Prix                              object
Sortie                         datetime64[ns]
Suppr                                 float64
Profit Center                          object
O / D                                  object
J-2 QTE NETTE                         float64
J-1 QTE NETTE                         float64
S-2 QTE NETTE                         float64
.....
dtype: object
```

I can manipulate the floats without any problems. 
But :
1) what is an object ? 
3) Any good tutorial to understand Object manipulation with Panda (couldn't find anything .... ) ?
2) What are his attributes ? 
And most importantly..... 
3) How can I manipulate it ?

I would like to select/find/ what's in this object when needed as I usually do with strings, int's, etc etc....

when :
    df['Artiste'] contains at least a string as 'oen' even if df['Artiste'] is 'Phoenix'

or when 
    df['Artiste'] contains exact "value" of 'Phoenix' = True

or sort by any possibility.. or replace....

---

### And weirdly, df['Référence'] type is an object but it's really only a number so should be a FLOAT64... when J-2 QTE NETTE is also a number but is typed as a FLOAT64

I understand that I'm stuck just because I don't understand well how to apprehend this 'Object' type... and couldn't find any meaningful informations online regarding my problem. 
I don't know if I should import differently the file by changing attributes/encoding, or if it's better to manipulate objects than strings (memory, calculations...), if I can convert these objects or else....

Any help is more than welcomed...

Comment: This is probably too broad. Basically, you are asking us to explain Python and the intricacies of numpy/pandas data structures. Essentially, anything the `dtype` of a `pandas` data structure is the `dtype` of the underlying `numpy` data structure. *Everything* in Python is an object. However, `numpy` essentially serves as a wrapper around C arrays. Arrays need equally spaced addresses (this is why they are fast and efficient), to do that with arbitrarily sized strings, you get arrays Python object pointers.

Comment: haha I'm asking at least for a clear tutorial/explanation of 'object' cause I can' find it...

Comment: In other words, here, objects are python `str` objects.

Comment: So, perhaps to answer your question more directly, just think of `object` as the most general `dtype`... when `pandas` can't infer something more specific (i.e. there is a mix of floats and strings in your column) then it makes the column `object` dtype. It can hold *anything* since *everything* in Python is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found by myself ! 
I was completly stuck. sincerely. for a few days...

Soooooo I don't know if it's the simple/easiest way but just decided to clean my csv files before importing them into my pandaframe :

- get rid of whitespaces or any non-numeric characters
- transforms the specific columns to float and strings
- create a new clean_csv file
- open it in panda

All good - working.